# Jenkins call http api after a build has completed

Tags: jenkins

## Context

I use poll policy to get the result of a build. But I want jenkins automatically push the result to me.

How to configure a job to call a http api after its build has completed?

For example, after a build has completed, jenkins call https://{myserver}/api/v1/jenkinsPostBuildCallback?jobName=name&buildNumber=1&result=Failed

## Current Attempt

I want to achieve this using jenkins plugins, but I find no plugin that meet my requirement.

Maybe I should develop a custom jenkins plugin?

Comment: Do the [Notification](https://plugins.jenkins.io/notification) or the [HTTP Request](https://plugins.jenkins.io/http_request) plugins answer your requirement?

Comment: Thanks, but i can't find the plugins in "manage jenkins" -> "manage plugins"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the post build select execute shell command and add a curl command to call your http api.